# Asking a large number of questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, multiple-questions

I have a number of questions I want to ask, but I wanted to know what is the best way to do this.

All my questions are DIY related, and some fit into a few categories, but are still separate questions.

Should I post them all separately, or am I best to ask them in small groups?

Answer (score 15):

Whenever I see multiple questions within a question on any site my first thought is to vote for closure as Needs More Focus because they will require multiple answers.

My recommendation would be to ask your most important question first because you can always research/ask your others separately.  On the [GIS Stack Exchange Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) we try to educate our new users on "one question per question" at the outset.

Often I think you will find that through the answer(s) to your first question, there will be pieces of information uncovered that may mean you already have the answer to what would have been other questions, that no longer need to be asked.

Personally I think more than about three questions in a day from the same user can be disrespectful to the efforts of our volunteers who will be doing their best to try and answer them.  Asking a question should not stop with asking it; you should also be attending to any clarifications sought by potential answerers through ongoing edits to improve your question.  We want each question to be of high quality.