# A gallery for a project which will involve multiple Stack Exchange questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, images, multiple-questions, gallery

My project is fixing up an old bicycle, but I think the question could apply to lots of sites, not just bicycles.

I am starting a project which is probably going to require (and be worthy of) several questions. I think I can make the questions "good": useful, not unique to me, etc. (I would like to think I have a reasonable grasp of the general principles of asking good questions, or at least I do on *[Bicycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour)*.)

It crossed my mind it would be useful to have one gallery where I can put up multiple photos, then refer to them from the individual questions.

For example, I have three problems: one with a wheel, one with the frame, and one with the seat. If I only ever had one problem and was only posting one question, I would probably put up three overview photos of the bike, and a few close ups. However, since I have three problems and three questions to ask, I would need to post the same overview photos for each question. And chances are that the close-up photos from one question might have detail in the background which might be useful for the other questions.

**Is there an established solution for providing a single gallery for multiple questions? Perhaps with some clever linking/referencing? Perhaps with a way to clearly number the photos?**

If nothing like that exists, could it be a useful feature request?

I know I can put all photos in a single album on google photos or similar - I am looking for something more clever.

**EDIT after question was closed:**

Firstly, I guess I need to address the first comment I received: "You can reference the same imgur [sic] upload in whatever questions you want" - this got ten upvotes by the time the question got closed.

My answer was that "the main reason I would see for a gallery was to avoid cluttering the question with tons of photos while giving viewers the option of seeing more photos of [sic] they want to". In other words, the comment seemed to be about the technicalities of adding pictures, while I was looking for something else completely: a way to improve the experience of those viewing the question.

Secondly, the site kept popping up with two "private recommendations" (or whatever it's called) at the top of my question, with potential duplicates identified by those commenting. There was an option for me to click "yes" or "no" to indicate if those questions answered my question. I pressed "no" for both of them, and explained why in the comments. But the site now says "This question already has answers here:" at the top, with the same questions linked:

- [Build and strengthen the Stack Exchange community with "crossover questions" between sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199989/build-and-strengthen-the-stack-exchange-community-with-crossover-questions-bet)
- [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735/282094)

I think that's a bit silly, if we go that way we will soon have a bot choosing the accepted answer for us.

Comment: You can reference the same imgur upload in whatever questions you want.

Comment: @RobertLongson the main reason I would see for a gallery was to avoid cluttering the question with tons of photos while giving viewers the option of seeing more photos of they want to.

Comment: You can provide links between your questions, even if they're not on the same site. They won't be automatically linked, but at least the context will carry over between them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735/282094)   https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/268258/282094  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318517/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317619/282094  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310771/282094 - each individual question must be a single and self-contained question, with one *best* answer.

Comment: @SonictheSaveUkraine-hog Thanks but no, all my questions would be on one site

Comment: @Rob Thanks but no. I am very conscious about the principle of *a single and self-contained question* - it's something I try to stick to in everyday work and personal comms too.

Comment: You can deny the duplicates, but that only makes the pop-up go away. If enough people think your question is a duplicate it will still get closed

Comment: That's not duplicate. Surely not of the cross site questions as it's about questions on single site, and as for several questions in one post, also different enough to justify separate question.

Comment: According to the bottom of [this answer testing images in the formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375239/293308), you should be able to size the images. You can make the less important images very small and people who want to view them can click on them to see them full size. (Not more clever than linking to a gallery but it should help with the space issue.)

Answer (score 5):

There's no need for a dedicated feature for this. Inline your most relevant images (`![alt text](link)`) and leave the rest as regular links (`[description](link)`). You can fit a number of links in a compact enough area with appropriate formatting, such as bullet points. You might not even need a direct link to a mostly irrelevant image if you're instead linking to another one of your questions that already contains that image.